# help needed with xpath ...please

Tags: xpath, selenium

I'm trying to write xpath for one of the elements in a tree-like structure in the UI.

The tree looks like a windows file structure, like parent node, child. So, in order to find child node parent node has to be clicked.

```
+ [file icon] Book
|_ Book 1
|_ Book 2
|_ Book 3
```

Selenium gives the following xpath for the text 'Book' in above tree shown

```
//ul[@id='book_xxx']/li/ul/li[8]/span
```

when I click on file icon, selenium gave me following

```
//ul[@id='book_xxx']/li/ul/li[8]/img[1]
```

How can one write an xpath for clicking the file icon(i.e image) based on knowing the span text? I need the xpath for clicking on file icon image.

Comment: It is easier to answer XPATH questions when sample XML is provided.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `span` and `img` elements are both children of the 8th `li` element, and I'm assuming the text inside the `span` that you would like to match on is "Book".

If you wanted to select the `span` filtering on the text you should be able to use:

`//ul[@id='book_xxx']/li/ul/li[span[text()='Book']]/img[1]`

This uses a nested predicate filter to identify the `li` that has a child `span` element who's text node value is "Book", and then selects that `li`'s first `img` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`//ul[@id='book_xxx']/li/ul/li[8]/img[1] | //ul[@id='book_xxx']/li/ul/li[8]/span`

Which is practically `xpath1 or xpath`.